# Installing crunchbang (grub) alongside WUBI

Tags: dual-boot, grub2, wubi, crunchbang

Is it possible to dual-boot with Ubuntu 12.04, Windows 7, and crunchbang? I have Ubuntu installed with WUBI, so there is a virtual drive inside my C:/ drive. If I were to install crunchbang normally in a partition, would it interfere with WUBI, since crunchbang uses grub?

Comment: I would recommend asking on the #! forums here if you get no answers ( because you are installing #! not Ubuntu http://crunchbang.org/forums/viewforum.php?id=4 )

Personally I doubt it would interfere because supposedly you would boot to #!/Windows GRUB and then go to the Windows/Ubuntu bootloader...but I don't actually KNOW...

Comment: I already asked on the #! forums, and there has been no response yet. Since it it mainly dealing with grub and WUBI, I decided to ask here too.

Comment: Fair enough....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wubi is not visible to other bootloaders. It's managed by the Windows boot manager, so you can install anything you like.

When you install another OS using e.g. Grub, it will add an entry for the new OS and Windows. When you select Windows you'll get the option to boot Wubi.

Wubi also runs Grub and when you update its `grub.cfg` i.e. by running `sudo update-grub` (or from a package update trigger) it will see the other OS. Then you'll find the Wubi Grub menu starts to appear (it's suppressed by default) and it will show the new OS in it (not Windows, which is automatically removed).

How does Grub find the Wubi install when running Wubi, but not when running a normal install? There is a package `lupin-support` which adds a script `/etc/grub.d/10_lupin` and this adds entries for Wubi. You can still boot a Wubi install from a normal Grub on your new OS, but you'd have to manually add the entries for it (not hard since you can just copy them from the Wubi install's grub.cfg to the other installs `/etc/grub.d/40_custom`)

Comment: Thought so! :D :P